# Обновление текста при нажатии checkbox

Tags: javascript

Есть код обновления адресной ссылки по нажатию на checkbox

```js
var w = document.querySelector('#wall'),
  a = document.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
w.onclick = function() {
  if (w.checked) {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=(?:[A-Za-z_0-9-]+\,?)*)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1wall,$2'));
  } else {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1$2'));
  }
  console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
}

var m = document.querySelector('#messages'),
  a = document.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
m.onclick = function() {
  if (m.checked) {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=(?:[A-Za-z_0-9-]+\,?)*)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1messages,$2'));
  } else {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1$2'));
  }
  console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<a href='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4113&scope=notify,&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token'><b>ссылке</b></a>
<input type="checkbox" id="wall">Отправка посто
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="messages">Работа с сообщениями
<br>
```

Все работает, но если перед ссылкой вставить другую ссылку, то код перестает работать. Пробовал менял `a = document.querySelectorAll('a')[0-на другие];` на 
`a = document.querySelectorAll('#someid')[0];`
К ссылке подставлял `id="someid"`. Он стал изменять первую ссылку, хотя у первой ссылки вообще не было id

Comment: У вас не структурирован документ, то есть нет никакой связи между заданным тегом Input  и тегом a. Поэтому добавление любого элемента с тегом a нарушает работу функции. Так же это совершенно бессмысленно использовать querySelector для элемента, имеющего id.  по крайней мере потому, что эта функция поддерживается лишь новыми браузерами и неэффективно по сравнению  с getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то Вы не договариваете. Все работает, если правильно обратиться к элементу

```js
var w = document.querySelector('#wall'),
  a = document.querySelectorAll('#link')[0];
w.onclick = function() {
  if (w.checked) {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=(?:[A-Za-z_0-9-]+\,?)*)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1wall,$2'));
  } else {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1$2'));
  }
  console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
}

var m = document.querySelector('#messages'),
  a = document.querySelectorAll('#link')[0];
m.onclick = function() {
  if (m.checked) {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=(?:[A-Za-z_0-9-]+\,?)*)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1messages,$2'));
  } else {
    a.setAttribute('href', a.getAttribute('href').replace(/^(.*\&scope\=)[^&]*(\&.*)$/, '$1$2'));
  }
  console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
<a href='https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=4113&scope=notify,&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token' id="link"><b>ссылке</b></a>
<input type="checkbox" id="wall">Отправка посто
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="messages">Работа с сообщениями
<br>
```

Comment: Объясните мне, какой смысл использовать querySelectorAll для элемента, имеющего id? Или вы стараетесь сделать функцию как можно более неэффективной?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Может автор потом навесит свои хитрые селекторы. Да `getElementById` тут было бы самое оно